# mac maven cannot find symbol wrong servlet-api.jar

Tags: macos, maven, servlets, classpath

I compile spring webflow samples project using maven in mac os and got errors. (The project compiled successfully in windows)

So I create a simple maven project to reproduce the error.

**pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>test</groupId>
 <artifactId>test</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0</version>

 <dependencies>
     <!-- Servlet -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 </project>
```

**src/main/java/Test.java**

```
 import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

 public class Test {
     public void init(ServletContext context) {
         context.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml");
     }
 }
```

**mvn compile**

The error is:
[image]

I thought is was something that maven used a wrong servlet-api.jar but not servlet as pom dependency specified which is correct. (I use `javac -cp javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar Test.java`, result no error)

I check `mvn dependency:tree`, the result show correct servlet-api-3.0.1.jar.

I also chech mvn script to see if there is some option to set classpath.
[image]

But I just can't figure out how maven use which jars as it's classpath.

Comment: A dependency which is defined with scope `provided` means it will be offered by the target environment where you jar will run. It will not made being part of your jar...In such cases you should create war instead but that will not change a thing...If you deploy a war to a servlet engine like Tomcat etc. there the servlet api is available and your war will work...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I know it. Even I try scope `compile` it still makes error. Now I import this maven project to eclipse. After that, I run `mvn compile` again, no error again. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

It's very weird.

After I've imported this test maven project into eclipse, 
I run `mvn compile` again, no error happened.